# How to keep user loggedIn in swift

Tags: xcode

How can i keep user logged in , it's not work for me. i write the code in login view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home");
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil);
        print("back to login page")

    } else {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login");
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil);
        print("back to home page")
    }
}
```

this's the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee8561fb8)

Comment: What line generates the error and what has the above code to do with keeping the user logged in?

Comment: in self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil); in else statement. and yes to keep user logged in

Comment: That line occurs twice but it doesn’t matter, have you checked that you have spelled the identifiers properly? And why are you force unwrapping `vc` instead of writing a proper `guard` statement so you can have some error handling? And you don’t need to answer, my questions are rethorical.

Comment: i'll tell you the answers if i solve it